# UINavigationBar title label text

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to get the title text to shrink to fit in the `UINavigationBar` in iOS.

(for portrait iPhone app with no autolayout).

I'm setting the title bar dynamically but sometimes the text is too long and at the moment it just cuts it off with an ellipsis.

i.e. "This is the t..."

I'd like it to shrink the text instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your own title view to make it.

Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  //Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     UILabel *titleLabelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)]; //<<---- Actually will be auto-resized according to frame of navigation bar;
    [titleLabelView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [titleLabelView setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [titleLabelView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [titleLabelView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 27]]; //<<--- Greatest font size
    [titleLabelView setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES]; //<<---- Allow shrink
     // [titleLabelView setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth:YES];  //<<-- Another option for iOS 6+
    titleLabelView.text = @"This is a Title";

    navigationBar.topItem.titleView = titleLabelView;

    //....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually done something similar to this already. Used a category on UILabel to create it for me quickly in all view controllers.

Answer (score 3):

```
Xcode 7.1 - Swift 2.0


//Adding Title Label
        var navigationTitlelabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        navigationTitlelabel.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        navigationTitlelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        navigationTitlelabel.textColor  = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navigationTitlelabel.text = "WORK ORDER"
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.titleView = navigationTitlelabel
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for swift 4 (note label rect is NOT important..)

```
func navBar()->UINavigationBar?{
        let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        return navBar
    }


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setTNavBarTitleAsLabel(title: "VERYYYY VERYYYY VERYYYY VERYYYY VERYYYY VERYYYY VERYYYY LONGGGGGG")
    }

    // will shrink label...

    func setTNavBarTitleAsLabel(title: String, color: UIColor ){

        // removed some code..

        let navigationTitlelabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        navigationTitlelabel.numberOfLines = 1
        navigationTitlelabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

        navigationTitlelabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        navigationTitlelabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
        navigationTitlelabel.textAlignment = .center
        navigationTitlelabel.textColor  = color
        navigationTitlelabel.text = title

        if let navBar = navBar(){
            //was navBar.topItem?.title = title

            self.navBar()?.topItem?.titleView = navigationTitlelabel
            //navBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : color ?? .black]
        }
    }
```