# Adjust navigation bar title font size to fit text

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to adjust the font size of the navigation bar's title to fit the text?

Comment: You can do this by setting the [title text attributes on the Navigation Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9621911/981388).

Comment: Okaay, and which attributes should I set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a UILabel and set it to UINavigationItem's titleView. See Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView

For the created UILabel, you can set the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth & minimumScaleFactor properties to let it fit the title. Doc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Some codes:

```
- (void)setMyTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.width - 100, 44)];
    titleLabel.text = title;
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    titleLabel.textColor = ...
    ...
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I found as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in viewDidLoad:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14] };

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```

NOTE: The downside to this solution is that you have to know the font size up front and set it manually. I'm not sure if you can set the navigation bar's title label to automatically change the font size to fit the text.

**EDIT:**
Turns out you can set the [navigation bar's label to resize the font size dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17860667/981388)

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5**

```
private var isFirst = true
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    guard isFirst else {
    return
    }
    isFirst = false
    // Adjust Navigation Title by text
    if let navigationController = navigationController {
    let bar = navigationController.navigationBar
    var minX: CGFloat = 0
    var maxX: CGFloat = bar.bounds.width
    if let lastLeft = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.last, let leftView = lastLeft.view, let buttonBarStackViewFrame = leftView.superview?.frame {
        minX = buttonBarStackViewFrame.maxX
    }
    if let firstRight = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.first, let rightView = firstRight.view, let buttonBarStackViewFrame = rightView.superview?.frame {
        maxX = buttonBarStackViewFrame.minX
    }

    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxX - minX, height: bar.bounds.height))
    titleLabel.text = LocStr(.favorite_master_title)
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.3
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    if UIDevice.current.modelName.contains(PLUS) {
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: GENERAL_FONT_NAME, size: PLUS_NAVIGATION_BAR_TITLE_FONT)!
    } else {
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: GENERAL_FONT_NAME, size: GENERAL_NAVIGATION_BAR_TITLE_FONT)!
    }
    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
    }
}
```

with a Extension

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    var view: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
    }
}
```